# Flask CSV to HTML Table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database.csv where I store my data and I would like to generate a table from it and show it on my html page. I tried to use pandas but getting the following error

"AttributeError: type object 'DataFrame' has no attribute 'from_csv'"

```
import pandas as pd

    @app.route("/table")
    def table():
        table = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("db/database.csv")
        return render_template("table.html", data=data)
```

I dont think it worth to show my html jinja content as I fails on this function. Could someone help how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To read a CSV file use `import pandas as pd
dataframe=pd.read_csv('data.csv')`

This returns a pandas dataframe